# Whom Did the Sons of Jacob Marry?

Tags: shevatim-12-tribes, intermarriage

The non-biblical book of [Jubilees chapter 34](https://www.sefaria.org/Book_of_Jubilees?tab=contents) (c. 2nd c. bce) preserves a tradition about the wives of Jacob's sons:

> 20. And after Joseph perished, the sons of Jacob took unto themselves wives. The name of Reuben's wife is ’Adâ and the name of Simeon's
>     wife is ’Adîbâ’a, a Canaanite; and the name of Levi's wife is Mêlkâ,
>     of the daughters of Aram, of the seed of the sons of Terah; and the
>     name of Judah's wife, Bêtasû’êl, a Canaanite; and the name of
>     Issachar's wife, Hêzaqâ; and the name of Zebulon's wife, †Nî’îmân†;
>     and the name of Dan's wife, ’Êglâ; and the name of Naphtali's wife,
>     Rasû’û, of Mesopotamia; and the name of Gad's wife, Mâka; and the name
>     of Asher's wife, ’Îjônâ; and the name of Joseph's wife, Asenath,  the
>     Egyptian; and the name of Benjamin's wife, ’Îjasaka. 21. And Simeon
>     repented, and took a second wife from Mesopotamia as his brothers (did).

I'm aware of biblical confirmation of only one these: Joseph's wife Asenath of Egypt (Gen. 41:45). The name of Judah's wife (prior to Tamar) is given as Shua in Gen. 38:1, and this could be the same person as  Bêtasû’êl. Are there Talmudic or other ancient references that shed led on the supposed wives of the Israelite tribal leaders?

Comment: Shua is the name of Judah’s father in law in Genesis 38.

Comment: @JoelK thanks... I was confused by the translation " there a daughter of a certain Canaanite whose name was Shua."  I suppose if she was bat-shua, this makes it even more likely that Jubilees' "Bêtasû’êl" is the same person.

Comment: @RabbiKaii ... Well, not fully, but it's basically the same question. Maybe there is no more to know. I have no objection to closing it as a duplicate.